# apply css to ie7 selected radio button

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I am using the following code to design my radio buttons on the page..

```
 input[type="radio"][disabled]  +label 
 {
     color: Aqua;
 } 
 input[type="radio"][checked]  +label 
 {
     font-weight: bold; 
     color: Red;
 }
```

The issue is that the [disabled] part is working fine, but the [checked] part is not working on IE7.
I know there is some pseudo class issue with this. 
But is there any work around to style the Selected radio button using CSS only?
I can not use Javascript or for that matter any Jquery plugin.. 
I need a solution either by css or anything in .aspx page.

I know this might be duplicate but the thing is that wherever I looked for the solution the only thing provided was to use javascript.. 
or some plugin.. (mostly selectivizr)....

I m looking for something in css only

Comment: I think you meant Server side as client side would be the browser and hence jQuery and JavaScript.  So you need a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this as it is not supported for IE7.  It is supported in IE9+.  There are some pollyfils out there but all that I have seen for `:checked` are in JavaScript and you said no JS.  ASPX will not help you either as it cannot manipulate the DOM or react to events once the page has been served, that's what JS does.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `input[type="radio"]:checked` instead.

Using `[checked]` only matches an element which has the "checked" attribute.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, missed the IE7 bit. It's impossible in IE versions prior to 9 without using a polyfill like Selectivizr. That's why it's so commonly linked elsewhere. There is no pure CSS way to do it. The browser just doesn't have enough CSS support to fake it without using Javascript.